# toolbar not showing options menu. (kotlin code)

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar, android-toolbar

Im a new coder looking to start app development, im trying to make a simple quiz app from the ground up to challenge myself, i basically just started this app and the toolbar isnt showing the option menu with the 3 dots on the top right, heres the code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="127dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="321dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

mainactivity.kt

```
package com.example.somethingnew

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }
}
```

i would appreciate any help i get on this, thanks in advance :)

Comment: May be you could add your menu xml file, if you have it. If you don't have it, then you should create it. You also need to override onCreateOptionsMenu method in your activity. Take a look at here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```